# Extracting a sub-document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that was a result of an aggregation query, and has documents with the following field structure:

```
{
   _id : { data1, data2 },
   data3
}
```

I would like to convert it to a "flat" structure like this:

```
{
   data1,
   data2,
   data3
}
```

What is the best way to accomplish this? Currently, I have in mind another aggregation query, but is there a simpler method?

Comment: Your resultant document will have to have an `_id` in any case. Can't you `$unwind` results from your original aggregation query?

Comment: Were you able to convert your data to the flat structure that you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The `_id` field is immutable, so you will not be able to change that. However, you are able to bring out the value in the subdocument you have in `_id` by adding the following `$project` clause to the end of your aggregation query.

```
{ $project: { "data1" : "$_id.data1", "data2": "$_id.data2", "data3": 1 } }
```

So your final aggregation query would look something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([ ..., 
                          { "$project": { "data1": "$_id.data1",
                                          "data2": "$_id.data2",
                                          "data3": 1 }
                          }
                        ]);
```

This will give you the flat structure you are looking for.